# Domain Name Redirect With Port On IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, port

I have a domain name and it's working on 80 port. 
How can I redirect this to 8080 port on IIS ?

I don't wanna use port number on url.

Example : www.abc.com is my site and it's working on 80 port. But www.abc.com needs to run on 8080 port and when I type to browser abc.com, it's need to open it on 8080 port.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Multiple sites (HTTP or HTTPS) can run at the same port if you use the right site bindings.

Answer (score 1):

URL rewrite can be used in this case. However 80 port is still required. You can only access website via www.abc.com with 8o port. So we need to creat a reverse proxy to forward 80 to 8080.

[image]

1.Please install failed request tracing and Application request routing.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

2.Add this rule to web.config.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="rewrite">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^80$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.example.com:8080/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

3.Enable proxy in IIS manager->server node->application request routing cache->server proxy drive->Enable proxy

4.You can access www.abc.com via 8080
[image]